# In matlab, how do I apply a function of two arguments to two cellarrays of equal length?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, cells

So I have two cell arrays:

```
A = {2 2 2 2}
B = {[1 2] [3 2] [5 5] [7 7]}
```

and a function of two arguments:

```
F = @(a, b) [a * b(1), (b(2) / 3), (b(1) + a) * 22]
```

And I want to apply the function to the two cell arrays like so:

```
idealfun(F, A, B)
```

and have it do the right thing (return a cell array with four cells of 1x3 vectors).  Any ideas how to find/write `idealfun`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html).

```
out = cellfun(F,A,B,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Ya, knew about cellfun, DID NOT KNOW IT WORKED FOR MULTIPLE CELL ARRAYS.  That is awesome.  Thank you.